# Newton's Method Polynomial solver in Ruby

Tags: beginner, ruby, numerical-methods

I am learning Ruby programming from "Learn Ruby the Hard way" and I am doing the "Ruby koans".

I have heard a little bit about "Idiomatic" Ruby but I don't know much about it. How can I make it more idiomatic?

```
# Program to solve polynomials

def solve(coeff)
    coefficients = []
    coeff.each{ |a|
        coefficients.push a.to_f
    }
    diffrentiate = []
    n = 0
    coefficients.reverse_each { |a| 
        diffrentiate.unshift n*a
        n += 1
    }
    diffrentiate.pop
    return newton(coefficients,diffrentiate,-1)
end

def newton(coefficients,diffrentiate,initialvalue)
    x = initialvalue
    10.times { |n|  
        x -= evaluate_polynomial(coefficients,x)/evaluate_polynomial(diffrentiate,x)
    }
    return x
end

def evaluate_polynomial(coefficients,x)
    n = 0
    value = 0
    coefficients.reverse_each { |a| 
        value += a*x**n
        n+=1
    }
    return value
end

puts solve ([1,0,0,0,-1,1])
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, an if you're just learning then just make it run and ask for tips on how to make it better. Idiomatic programming can be tricky and chances are with your coding up there, you'll probably get about twelve different answers that are the same written differently, for an example see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364113/whats-a-more-idiomatic-ruby-way-of-writing-this Ruby is all about being easy to read and write. Just have fun with it, that's what counts and never let anybody tell you that you're wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Use `do...end` instead of `{...}` for multi-line blocks.
2. `return` is implicit at the end of a method.
3. `differentiate` is a verb. `derivatives` is the plural noun you're looking for when naming the array.
4. Use Ruby's array methods (`map`, `reduce`, and friends) to your advantage.
5. Don't modify external variables from inside a block if you can avoid it. I.e. don't do things like `n += 1`, or `x -= ...`. A combination of `with_index` and `reduce` should do the same trick more neatly.
6. There's some repetition in your handling of the order of coefficients (i.e. the `n += 1` in the blocks). It'd be nice to get rid of that.
7. It'd be nice to specify the number of iterations the approximation should use.

Here's a pretty direct translation of your solution:

```
# Add a method to Array which zips the array with the index
# of each element in reverse order
class Array
  def zip_reverse_index
    zip((0...count).to_a.reverse)
  end
end

# Use a *-splat to make the method variadic
def solve(*coefficients)
  coefficients.map!(&:to_f)
  derivatives = coefficients.zip_reverse_index.map { |n, i| n * i }
  newton(coefficients, derivatives[0...-1])
end

# Added some (optional) arguments
def newton(coefficients, derivatives, iterations = 10, initial = -1)
  iterations.times.reduce(initial) do |x, i|
    x -= evaluate_polynomial(coefficients, x) / evaluate_polynomial(derivatives, x)
  end
end

# A simpler implementation using reduce
def evaluate_polynomial(coefficients, x)
  coefficients.zip_reverse_index.reduce(0) do |sum, (c, n)|
    sum += c * x ** n
  end
end
```

---

Here's a different version that keeps everything in 1 method:

```
def newton_raphson(coefficients, intial = -1, iterations = 10)
  evaluate = -> (array, x) do
    array.reduce(0) { |sum, (c, ord)| sum += c * x ** ord }
  end

  coefficients = coefficients
    .map(&:to_f) 
    .zip((0...coefficients.count).to_a.reverse)

  derivatives = coefficients.map { |c, ord| [c * ord, ord - 1] }[0...-1]

  iterations.times.reduce(intial) do |approx, _|
    approx -= evaluate[coefficients, approx] / evaluate[derivatives, approx]
  end
end
```

It's pretty long for a Ruby method, but some of the methods in the other implementation seemed too specific to keep around in the global scope (and the `Array` mixin also seemed a little heavy-handed).

---

Edit: as @jQweirdy mentioned in the comments, this could also be solved with a class, but I was hesitant to add a class just for one method. But there are a few things here, that might be generically useful for `Polynomial` class. So here's an example:

```
class Polynomial
  attr_reader :coefficients

  def initialize(*coefficients)
    @coefficients = coefficients
  end

  def evaluate(x)
    coefficients.zip(ordinals).reduce(0) do |sum, (n, i)|
      sum += n * x ** i
    end
  end

  def derivative
    @derivative ||= begin
      derivatives = coefficients.zip(ordinals)[0...-1].map { |n, i| n * i }
      self.class.new(*derivatives)
    end
  end

  def order
    coefficients.count - 1
  end

  def ordinals
    (0..order).to_a.reverse
  end

  def newton_raphson_approximation(iterations = 1, initial = -1)
    iterations.times.reduce(initial) do |x, _|
      x -= evaluate(x).fdiv(derivative.evaluate(x))
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: isn't ruby 'idiomatically' object oriented? Couldn't you change your code to be more OO (like the first example) without the 'public methods floating about? Maybe a `Polynomial` class?

Comment: @jQwierdy I saw your answer before it was removed. And yes, it could be put into a class. However, here the goal is only to implement the Newton-Raphson approximation, so you're looking at a _function_ rather than a class with methods. It's pure input → output with no state being kept. But yes, it could be a class. I'd just like to add few more polynomial-manipulation methods to "justify" the class. In this case, `derivatives` could be such a method - the usefulness of something like that is not exclusive to the Newton approximation.

Comment: I get what you're saying, and I love functional programming but you're going against the "send messages" OO part of ruby - aren't you? Even stateless classes, or a non-instatiatable class would be better than floating methods - wouldn't it?

Comment: @jQwierdy Sure, certainly better than methods floating around in global scope. But that's also why I added the alternative that just keeps everything in 1 method, just to contain it. There are many ways to structure all of this. This was a learning project according to OP, not something part of a larger code base, so even keeping things in the global scope would be ok for now. I just looked at micro level (how to produce the desired result with different code) and less at the macro level (how to structure the thing). So you're right - it just seemed out-of-scope for this review.

Comment: Fair enough! Thanks for the detailed response. :-)

Comment: @jQwierdy No problem - and I encourage you to add an review that tackles the structure by suggesting a class. Just start with OP's code/post, so your answer is a direct response to that. You're free to copy over my code too of course, but your answer should be made in reply to the question - not another answer. I often write things like "Other answer(s) already pointed out X, but I'd just like to add something about Y...". The more reviews, the merrier.